# How to find type of Annotated function parameter

Tags: java, annotations, rest

Suppose I have a function

```
public int doSomething(@QueryParam("id") String name, int x){ .... }
```

How can I find the type of the annotated parameter 'name'. I have a handle to the `java.lang.reflect.Method` instance of the function doSomething and using the function `getParameterAnnotations()`, I can obtain the annotation `@QueryParam` but am not able to access the parameter on which it is applied on. How do I do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
void doSomething(@WebParam(name="paramName") int param) {  }

Method method = Test.class.getDeclaredMethod("doSomething", int.class);
Annotation[][] annotations = method.getParameterAnnotations();

for (int i = 0; i < annotations.length; i ++) {
    for (Annotation annotation : annotations[i]) {
        System.out.println(annotation);
    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
@javax.jws.WebParam(targetNamespace=, partName=, name=paramName, 
     header=false, mode=IN)
```

To explain - the array is two dimensional because first you have an array of parameters, and then for each parameter you have an array of annotations.

You can verify the type of the annotation you expect with `instanceof` (or `Class.isAssignableFrom(..)`.